# Vue.js error: Named slots must use '<template>' on a custom element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs-slots

I am trying to pass information through slots and I keep getting an error,

> 'Named slots must use '' on a custom element.'

See below for my code.

```
    <template>
        <div>
            <h3>Home</h3>
            <User v-slot:user="{ user }">
                <template>
                <div v-if="user">
                    <p>Logged-in as {{user.uid}} </p>
    
                    <!-- PASS USER STATE AS PROP -->
                    <UserProfile :user="user"/> 
                    <ChatList :uid="user.uid"/>
                </div>
                <Login v-else/>
                </template>
            </User>
        </div>
    </template>
```

I get an error on the following line.

```
    <User v-slot:user="{ user }">
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your component names, I suspect the `User` component contains the "user" slot.

The `v-slot` should be on a `<template>` within the `<User>` tags:

```html
<User>           
  <template v-slot:user="{ user }">
    <div v-if="user">
      <p>Logged-in as {{ user.uid }}</p>
    </div>

    <Login v-else />
  </template>
</User>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-named-slots?file=src/App.vue)